# Can't change code copied from form in different database

Tags: vba, ms-access

Building a Maintenance log book in access.  Had to redo a data entry form so I started over with a new form in a new database then copied some working code from the old form to the new. In doing so I changed the names of a couple of combo boxes in the new form in order to keep things consistent.  Problem is, the code I copied has the old name of some of the combo boxes and I can't change those names to the new names.  The new names don't present when using autofill, just the old ones.  Is there a way to correct that.(Easy, I Hope)

Example: in the old form the name of a combo box was actionCB.  In the new form the box is named ActionCB, but now any code I write uses the old name.

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening because you have compilation errors. Try compiling the application and fixing any errors. Or possibly this could happen if you happened to be stepping through the code at the same time (but I doubt it from your description)? Also VBA is beautiful in the fact that almost always you can make code changes while stepping through the code... but I've experienced the changes not saving from time to time.

**MODIFIED FOR NEW QUESTION**
As to your second question below in the comments. You can view and select a Form or Reports controls by using the Forms Property Sheet. If you look at the combobox at the very top of the property sheet it lists all Form or Report controls. You can select these objects by simply selecting them from the combobox.[image]

Comment: As @Anthony Griggs says, Debug | Compile will show compile error - Autosense usually stops working when there's an error in your code

Comment: Compile found two errors that I corrected, but that code was extraneous and left over from something that was removed. But, it did not fix the problem, and I don't want to change the new control name to the old control name, again, for the sake of consistency. Are all the control names in the object browser, and if so how do I find them? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Access is not case sensitive

> "Example: in the old form the name of a combo box was actionCB. In the
>   new form the box is named ActionCB, but now any code I write uses the
>   old name."

If you're code is not updating to reflect the "ActionCB" name automatically, then you're probably trying to reference it where it's not available. This isn't going to generate an error if you don't have `Option Explicit` statement at the top of your module.

It'll just assume you know what you're doing and assign it to a Variant data type.

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of all your modules, and the debug | compile untill all errors are fixed.

Comment: I put Option Explicit above the module in question ab and it put it at the end of the previous module.  When I recompiled i got an error "Only comments can appear after and End Sub. I even deleted the form that I pinched the code from.  no change.

Comment: Why "and I put it at the end of the previous module". All I said was to "Put Option Explicit at the top of all your modules"